# Wrong result when executing select query with != condition in Oracle database 21

Tags: java, database, oracle

After the execution of a query in Oracle, the results are shown incorrectly. It seems like some data are cached and as a result, the outcome is not correct. By changing some conditions in where clauses (especially the conditions that are related to “not equal”), the results are shown accurately. This happens in many queries, but the first occurrence was in Queries with high execution count.

Query Example:

```sql
SELECT TB_MODEL.ID
FROM TB_MODEL
WHERE TB_MODEL.SUBJECT = ? AND TB_MODEL.STATUS <> ? AND TB_MODEL.PARENT_ID IS NOT NULL
```

Result:
EMPTY (I am sure there is data in the database with the desired conditions)

Sometimes, but not always, with resetting the Oracle database, this problem dissolves.

Oracle RAC Version: 21.3.0.0.0

JDBC Driver: 23.3.0.23.09

**update 1:**

this sample code reurn 0:

```java
String query = "SELECT TB_MODEL.ID
FROM TB_MODEL
WHERE TB_MODEL.SUBJECT = ? AND TB_MODEL.STATUS <> ? AND TB_MODEL.PARENT_ID IS NOT NULL";

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.1.10:1521/dbk", "dbk", "dbk");
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setByte(1, (byte) 3);
statement.setByte(2, (byte) 5);

ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
int count = 0;
while (resultSet.next()) {
    count++;
}
return count;
```

this sample code reurn 0:

and this one return 313!

```java
String query = "SELECT TB_MODEL.ID
FROM TB_MODEL
WHERE TB_MODEL.SUBJECT = ? AND TB_MODEL.STATUS <> 5 AND TB_MODEL.PARENT_ID IS NOT NULL";

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.1.10:1521/dbk", "dbk", "dbk");
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setByte(1, (byte) 3);

ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
int count = 0;
while (resultSet.next()) {
    count++;
}
return count;
```

**update 2:**

1. This problem happens for queries that have an inequality condition (`<>`)
2. The problem is solved by changing the binding value (`?`) with its fixed value in the inequality condition (`TB_MODEL.STATUS <> ?` -> `TB_MODEL.STATUS <> 3`).

Comment: Did you `COMMIT` your data?

Comment: Select the condition columns too. Remove one condition at the time and see what happens. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: @MT0 data already exist in database.

Comment: thx @user85421, It was also tested with <> and the response from the database is still wrong

Comment: are any of the bind variables NULL or empty  ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie
No, they have a value and are not empty
The question description was edited

Comment: Have you tried `setInt()` rather than `setByte()`? If should not make a difference but different drivers may have slightly different implementations.

Comment: @MT0 Tested with `setInt()` and still the problem is there :(

Comment: @user85421
That's right, the code was extracted from debug mode and needed a little modification, `==` repalced with `=`.

Comment: This is going to be a client programming issue with how to properly set up binds. This will not be due to anything the Oracle database is doing. You may want to enable a 10046 trace at level 4 or higher so you can capture the exact SQL cursor that was parsed on the database side and the bind values used. That can help determine what your client is doing incorrectly.

Comment: what is the datatype of those 2 columns ? They seem to be NUMBER. Have you tried using setInt instead of setByte in your calling code ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie
the data type of type and status is `NUMBER(2,0)`

Comment: @PaulW
thx paul, we capture sql query with tcpdump and in oracle trace logs, everything is ok, both sql query and biding values :(

Comment: @Rajin I asked 2 questions, you only answered the first one....

Comment: @KoenLostrie
Tested with setInt() and still the problem is there.


`@MT0` asked this question earlier :D.

Comment: @jarlh
The problem is solved by changing the binding value (`?`) with its fixed value in the inequality condition (`TB_MODEL.STATUS <> ?` -> `TB_MODEL.STATUS <> 3`).

Comment: @Rajin, can you please share the SQL cursor parse in and bind section of the 10046 trace in your post?

Comment: Please post the DDL for TB_MODEL.

Answer (score 0):

Un`COMMIT`ted data is only visible within the session that created it (and will `ROLLBACK` at the end of the session if it has not been `COMMIT`ted). If you can't see the data from another session (i.e. in C#) then make sure you have issued a `COMMIT` command in the SQL client where you `INSERT`ed the data (i.e. SQL Developer).

*Note: even if you connect as the same user, this will create a separate session and you will not be able to see the uncommitted data in the other session.*

From the [`COMMIT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COMMIT.html#GUID-6CD5C9A7-54B9-4FA2-BA3C-D6B4492B9EE2):

> Until you commit a transaction:
>
> - You can see any changes you have made during the transaction by querying the modified tables, but other users cannot see the changes. After you commit the transaction, the changes are visible to other users' statements that execute after the commit.
> - You can roll back (undo) any changes made during the transaction with the `ROLLBACK` statement (see `ROLLBACK`).

Therefore, even if you say:

> data already exist in database.

That does not matter if it was created in another session and has not been `COMMIT`ted as it will not be visible to any other session. You need to ensure that you `COMMIT` your data.

Comment: The problem is not transaction isolation level, just by replacing the first binding value with constant value and execute query in the same session, everything works correctly and the result is correct.
The problem seems to be in the Oracle database and its caching parameter and mechanisms.